# Adding today's date as a parameter with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

What I want is to add today's date as a parameter in a domain if it contains a specific host, so going to:

```
www.example.com/whatever/whatever.htm?var1=bla&var2=blabla
```

does nothing, but going to

```
date.example.com/whatever/whatever.htm?var1=bla&var2=blabla
```

Should redirect to

```
www.example.com/whatever/whatever.htm?var1=bla&var2=blabla&date=2016-03-06
```

with the `date=` parameter being dynamic according to today's date.

The redirection should be a 301. From what I have been searching I think I should use `[QSA,R=301,L]` and either `%Y-%m-%d` or `%{TIME_YEAR}-%{TIME_MON}-%{TIME_DAY}` for the date.

I also "know" about `{QUERY_STRING}` and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, so I think I have all the pieces, but putting together is what is proving challenging. I managed to do a simple redirection where I redirect one specific URL to another one, but adding the date dynamically, changing the host etc. is proving to be way over my head as I have never touched `.htaccess` before.

Comment: you can always check date in PHP itself. or you could check in PHP if URL doesn't have that date in the request, and use header('') to redirect there. It will be simpler for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to add the current date  perameter to query string :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^date\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /whatever/whatever\.htm\?var=([^&]+)&var2=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI}?var1=%1&var2=%2&date=%{TIME_YEAR}-%{TIME_MON}-%{TIME_DAY} [NE,NC,L,R]
```

The code above will redirect an incomming request of the form :

- http://date.example.com/whatever/whatever.htm?var1=foo&var2=bar

to this :

- http://example.com/whatever/whatever.htm?var1=foo&var2=bar&time=2016-03-06